# Run Python program from any folder in the file system when the path to the py is in my path environment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I can call a python script as `M:\GIS_Library\Vector_Data\Infrastructure\Transport\Roads>>>> python3 "z:\my drive\scripts\rename.py"` when I am in a different folder. However I would really like to run scripts as `>>> python3 rename.py` even when I am not in the folder with the .py file for it to execute on the files in the folder I am currently in.

[image]

In my environment variables I have

[image]

and in py3env.bat I have

```
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts
PATH %PYTHONPATH%;%PATH%;Z:\My Drive\scripts
```

Could part of the issue be with the darn space in the drive folder (can't change this).

Comment: So you are asking the python interpreter to search your path looking for the file rename.py and interpret it when it finds it?

Comment: I guess...so it should look in each of the folders that are defined as the path in my environment labels for the .py file and then execute it. The same as me typing `python3 "z:\folder\folder2\script.py"` but simply letting me not have to type the full path to the .py file.  With exe files we can do this.

Comment: Maybe try `SET PYDIR="z:\my drive\scripts\"`, then call the script with `python %PYDIR%\rename.py`. Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I get the same error. I did notice though that if I call the python file from a .bat file, it works and so I can run the batch file from any folder without having to specify the folder the .bat file is in.

Comment: The windows command terminal knows to search your Path from you environment strings for files like '.exe', '.bat', '.cmd' and some others.  But the problem is, the python interpreter won't search that way for its argument.  You may be able to register the '.py' extension with windows such that you could type just 'rename.py' and the command terminal will find it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding the folder to the path and then creating a .bat that has `python3 "full path to .py"` works perfectly. It also then makes it accessible to cmd based iteration etc.

It can then be called from any folder as just c:\somefolder\filename.py and it would run in the same folder as it's called from.